# Is it possible to resize the website by 1 pixel with a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am currently trying to implement a collapsible section on a wordpress website, that when it is visible instead collapses the upper section and vice versa.
Both sections contain a wordpress gallery and while the collapsing itself works, something with the galleries is wrong so they dont show. However they do appear when I resize my Browserwindow. So I was wondering if it is possible to pair the collapse function with a function that resizes the website/window by 1 pixel, so the galleries will show then?

I am currently using the following code:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    var contentcoll = this.previousElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
      contentcoll.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
      contentcoll.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
}
//However, the themeprovider also urges you to use the following code, when using Galleries with tabs/collapsibles, maybe I just need to change something with that?

jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
  jQuery(".panel-group").on(
    'show.bs.collapse',
    function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
      }, 400);
    }
  );
});
```

```css
.collapsible {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5px !important;
  display: block
}

.content {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.contentcoll {
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  padding-top: 0px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contentcoll">
  [vc_column_text css=".vc_custom_1590495248381{margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px !important; margin-bottom: 0px !important;border-bottom-width: 0px !important;padding-bottom: 0px !important;}"]</p>
  <h3 class="font-173606 h3 font-weight-500" style="color: #183f74; margin-top: 0px;">Unsere Highlights:</h3>
  <p>[/vc_column_text] [vc_gallery el_id="gallery-114657" medias="2708,2668,2664,2662,2658,2656,2654,2652,2650" gutter_size="3" media_items="media|lightbox|poster,icon" screen_lg="1000" screen_md="600" screen_sm="480" single_overlay_opacity="50" single_padding="2"]
    <p style="text-align: center; color: #183f74; margin-top: 10px;">Die ist nur eine kleine Auswahl...</p>
</div>

<button type="button" class="collapsible"><img src="https://baermedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/mehr.png" id="imgClickAndChange" onclick="changeImage()"></button>
<div class="content">
  [vc_gallery el_id="gallery-103603" medias="2605,2648,2618,2620,2622,2624,2626,2628,2631,2633,2639,2645,2613,2609,2603,2597,2594,2592,2590,2588,2586,2545,2547,2549,2561,2563,2567,2571,2573,2578,2584,2534,2530,2506,2504,2495,2493,2491,2488,2486,2484,1872,1873,2479,2482"
  filtering="yes" filter_back_color="color-xsdn" filtering_full_width="yes" filtering_position="center" gutter_size="3" media_items="media|lightbox|poster,icon" screen_lg="1000" screen_md="600" screen_sm="480" single_overlay_opacity="50" single_padding="2"]
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to make you a snippet. Please update it to look like you need.What is `[vc_column_text ...` for example?

Comment: I suggest not trying to hack around the problem, but to fix the underlying issue that prevents the gallery from being shown in the first place. That just seems like bad practice. As a sidenote, I would also suggest not writing CSS in your javascript unless absolutely necessary. Things like setting `display: block;` can be easily achieved using classes, which then cleans up your javascript code and might very well make problems like these easier to solve.

Comment: @vrugtehagel While I am absolutely aware it is bad practise to try to workaround the problem, I just got thrown into this WP-topic and do not have the knowledge to fix it properly, and the boss wants fast results...
Also for the css in js I just followed this guide: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp
But I will keep it in mind, thanks for making me aware! :)

Comment: @mplungjan The [vc_colum_text...] is shortcode created by the visual composer with the theme, and thanks I will try if I can make the snippet work.

Comment: @mplungjan Unfortunately, while your snippet does run properly, it did not fix the problem. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: it was not my snippet. It was a snippet I made of YOUR code that YOU was supposed to create for us, but that I decided to try to do to make it easier to figure out what the problem is. I was not trying to fix anything in your question

Comment: Oh, I misunterstood, I am sorry. I just saw the extra line for the jquery-script. The problem is, the snippet will not display the problem, as the gallery I am using only works with the wordpress-theme... I can record a video of the problem though.